wireshark, что означает флаг С?
Что означает в wireshark в параметрах

Flags: ........C,

Что означает флаг С?

Флаг в wireshark где конкретно?

-C <config profile>      start with specified configuration profile (https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChCustCommandLine.html)

@PakUula не об этих флагах речь
